# Floatable power supply one one side of isolation amplifier

Tags: power-supply

I am making a circuit where I need to float one part of the circuit with (-200V) I am using isolating amplifiers [ISO124](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso124.pdf) to isolate that part of the circuit.

An image below should explain what I am trying to say. 
[image]

The part in the orange box is isolated and floated to -200V (floating ground, FGND). The problem I am having is finding  power supply  for the op amps on the floatable side of the circuit. The parts outside the orange box can be floated easily with any +- 15V power supply. What do I do with the part inside the orange box?

I have researched a bit and found several DC-DC isolated power supplies, but I am not sure how to float them so that I can have 200+15 V and 200-15 V power supply for the opamps in the floatable region.

I guess what I am asking is if there is a isolating  power supply device something like this? 
[image]

Where there are three terminals on the output side ( right) and I can float it to whatever I want. If not? what other choices do I have. I have seen many people using optocouplers and isolating amps, there has to be something people do to power opamps in the floating side.

I can use the DC-DC isolated power supplies, but I not only have to float the FGND, but also the rail voltages of the op-amps relative to FGND like so:

[image]

I want the rail voltages to be FGND+15V and FGND-15V and not, FGND+30V and FGND .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a DC-DC converter, like the Racom [REC10-xx15DRW](http://www.recom-international.com/pdf/Econoline/REC10-SRW_DRW_Z_Hx.pdf).

Alternatively you can use a mains powered +/- 15 V power supply, like the Racom [RAC15-15DB](http://www.recom-international.com/pdf/Powerline-AC-DC/RAC15-S_D_TB.pdf), which can supply 2 x 500 mA at an 82 % efficiency. Isolation voltage is 4 kV AC.

**edit** re your update of the question
A dual power supply has 3 connections: the +15 V, the -15 V and ground, which is what the + and - are referred to. That's your floating ground. (If the supply wouldn't have that ground it would be a single +30 V supply.)

[image]

Comment: Well, the problem I face is how to float the +/- 15 V, if I float the - ve end, the +ve end will be (Floated voltage + 30 V), What I need for the rail voltages of the opamp are : FGND +15V and FGND -15 V. Not, FGND and FGND +30V.

Comment: @Ender - Sorry, I don't understand that. Obviously the +15 V of a +/- 15 V supply will be 30 V higher than the -15 V. That will always be so, whether the supply is floating or connected to another voltage. The idea is that you use this floating supply to feed the right side of the isolation amplifier, so that the incoming signal is referenced to this floating supply.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question and added a figure to explain what I meant. Hopefully it makes it a little clear.

Comment: @Ender - OK, I got it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any isolated DC-DC converter will work fine in this application. Just make sure you check its datasheet for the maximum input-to-output differential it is rated for. Most are at least 1500V, so you should be fine. You can connect your "FGND" to the -200V inside the orange box.

Comment: I not only need to float the FGND, but also the rail voltages of the op am relative to the floating potential.

Comment: Yes, they'll float relative to FGND, just as @stevenvh has shown.